# Respond to a fulfilled CreateAsyncThunk from another slice

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

I have a simple e-commerce app I am working on migrating from vanilla redux to redux-toolkit. I have 2 slices a userSlice and a cartSlice. What I am trying to do is trigger a clearCart action from cartSlice when my signOut createAsyncThunk gets fulfilled.

My userSlice:

```
    import {
  createSlice,
  createSelector,
  createAsyncThunk,
  isAnyOf,
} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import {
  auth,
  googleProvider,
  facebookProvider,
  getSnapshotFromUserAuth,
  getCurrentUser,
} from "../../firebase/firebase.utils";

//state
const initialState = {
  currentUser: null,
  error: null,
};

//signIn with google async thunk
export const signInWithGoogle = createAsyncThunk(
  "user.signInWithGoogle",
  async (_, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const { user } = await auth.signInWithPopup(googleProvider);
      return getSnapshotFromUserAuth(user);
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue({ error: error.message });
    }
  }
);

//sign in with email and password
export const signInWithEmailAndPassword = createAsyncThunk(
  "user.emailSignIn",
  async ({ email, password }, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const { user } = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      return getSnapshotFromUserAuth(user);
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.message);
    }
  }
);

//get current user
export const checkUserSession = createAsyncThunk(
  "user.getCurrentUser",
  async (_, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const userAuth = await getCurrentUser();
      if (!userAuth) {
        return;
      }
      return getSnapshotFromUserAuth(userAuth);
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.message);
    }
  }
);

//sign out user
export const signOut = createAsyncThunk(
  "user.signOut",
  async (_, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      await auth.signOut();
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.message);
    }
  }
);

//user slice
export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(signOut.fulfilled, (state) => {
        state.currentUser = null;
      })
      .addMatcher(
        isAnyOf(
          signInWithGoogle.fulfilled,
          signInWithEmailAndPassword.fulfilled,
          checkUserSession.fulfilled
        ),
        (state, { payload }) => {
          state.currentUser = payload;
        }
      )
      .addMatcher(
        isAnyOf(
          signOut.rejected,
          signInWithGoogle.rejected,
          signInWithEmailAndPassword.rejected,
          checkUserSession.rejected
        ),
        (state, { payload }) => {
          state.error = payload;
        }
      );
  },
});

//reducer export
export default userSlice.reducer;

//selectors export
const selectUser = (state) => state.user;

export const selectCurrentUser = createSelector(
  [selectUser],
  (user) => user.currentUser
);

export const selectError = createSelector([selectUser], (user) => user.error);
```

and my cart slice

```
    import { createSlice, createSelector } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { addItemToCart, removeItemFromCart } from "../../redux/cart/cart.utils";

//sttate
const initialState = {
  hidden: true,
  cartItems: [],
};

//cart slice
export const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    toggleCartHidden: (state) => {
      state.hidden = !state.hidden;
    },
    addItem: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.cartItems = addItemToCart(state.cartItems, payload);
    },
    clearItemFromCart: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.cartItems = state.cartItems.filter(
        (cartItem) => cartItem.id !== payload.id
      );
    },
    removeItem: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.cartItems = removeItemFromCart(state.cartItems, payload);
    },
    clearCart: (state) => {
      return (state.cartItems = []);
    },
  },
});

//export action creators
export const {
  toggleCartHidden,
  addItem,
  clearItemFromCart,
  removeItem,
  clearCart,
} = cartSlice.actions;

//export reducer
export default cartSlice.reducer;

//export selectors
const selectCart = (state) => state.cart;

export const selectCartItems = createSelector(
  [selectCart],
  (cart) => cart.cartItems
);

export const selectCartHidden = createSelector(
  [selectCart],
  (cart) => cart.hidden
);

export const selectCartTotal = createSelector([selectCartItems], (cartItems) =>
  cartItems.reduce(
    (accumulatedQuantity, cartItem) =>
      accumulatedQuantity + cartItem.quantity * cartItem.price,
    0
  )
);

export const selectCartItemsCount = createSelector(
  [selectCartItems],
  (cartItems) =>
    cartItems.reduce(
      (accumulatedQuantity, cartItem) =>
        accumulatedQuantity + cartItem.quantity,
      0
    )
);
```

Following the guidelines provided by the redux toolkit I tried importing my clearCart action from my cartSlice and use thunkAPI dispatch method inside my SignOut thunk to dispatch clearCart after awaiting for auth.signOut() but then I get a rejected status because Immer complains that I am both returning a new value AND modifying the draft.

Can someone please tell me what am I missing here? With vanilla Redux it would be plain easy to subscribe to my SIGNOUT_SUCCESS action and create a saga to yield clearCart.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**
The problem with the above strategy was that I was using return inside the cartslice reducer clearCart function. Removing return solved the issue. I could successfully dispatch clearCart from signOut thunk and update both currentUser state and cartItems state.